# python scheduler change by some condition

Tags: python, scheduler

I try to write the code that runs a job every 10 seconds when flag is 1 and every 20 seconds when flag is 2, but it's not correct and I don't really think it's a good approach. Is it the better way change time interval the code running?

```
import schedule
import time

flag = 1  

def job():
    if flag == 1:
        print("Running job every 10 seconds (flag = 1)")
    elif flag == 2:
        print("Running job every 20 seconds (flag = 2)")

def change_flag(new_flag):
    global flag
    flag = new_flag


schedule.every(10).seconds.do(job)

while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)

    # change the flag from 1 to 2 after 30 seconds
    if schedule.get_job(job).seconds == 30:
        change_flag(2)
      
        schedule.clear_job(job)
        schedule.every(20).seconds.do(job)
```

**Output:**

```
Job 2 executed
Job 2 executed
Job 2 executed
Job 1 executed
Job 1 executed
Job 1 executed
Job 1 executed
Job 1 executed
Job 1 executed
Job 1 executed
Job 1 executed
Job 1 executed
Job 1 executed
Job 2 executed
Job 2 executed
Job 2 executed
Job 1 executed
Job 1 executed
Job 1 executed
Job 1 executed
Job 1 executed
Job 1 executed
Job 1 executed
Job 1 executed
Job 1 executed
Job 1 executed
Job 2 executed
Job 2 executed
Job 2 executed
Job 2 executed
```